# How can i splice current index in a foreach?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, splice

I have this foreach loop to check for collision and i want platform(movieclip) to be removed in case of collision. So far i've come up with this:

```
if (mcContent.mcPlayer.y + mcContent.mcPlayer.height > platformCloud.y) 
                                {
                                    mcContent.mcPlayer.y = platformCloud.y - mcContent.mcPlayer.height - 1;
                                    jump();
                                    mcContent.removeChild(platformCloud);
                                    //platformsCloud.splice(platformCloud);
                                }
```

What this is doing is, removing the movieclip (ok so far so good) but without the splice, when the loop runs again through the array it is still there. So with the splice that is commented out there's 1 little problem, it removes all the movieclips from the array, apprently.

How can i splice only the current index that is being checked?

Comment: Why do you want to keep references to objects that have been removed? Does it makes sense to keep them in the same place as "active" objects?

Comment: i don't that's why i am removing them with removeChild and then taking them out of the array so they won't be checked for again. At least that's what i am trying to achieve with this piece of code.

Comment: In a `forEach` loop? [Don't!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811630/splicing-a-javascript-array-from-within-the-callback-passed-to-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.splice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) accepts a start index and an amount of items to remove, not the object you want to remove from the array.

> **Parameters**
>
> `startIndex:int` — An integer that specifies the index of the element in the array where the insertion or deletion begins. You can use a negative integer to specify a position relative to the end of the array (for example, -1 is the last element of the array).
>
> `deleteCount:uint` — An integer that specifies the number of elements to be deleted. This number includes the element specified in the startIndex parameter. If you do not specify a value for the deleteCount parameter, the method deletes all of the values from the startIndex element to the last element in the array. If the value is 0, no elements are deleted.

You want to do this:

```
var index:int = platformsCloud.indexOf(platformCloud);
platformsCloud.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: at work now but we'll definetly look into it when i get home, this seems like the right use, i'm learning as3 alone that's why i had the incorrect use of it, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a *new* array of the items to keep? Use `Array.push` to add new items. This *may* actually be more efficient than modifying the existing array. It also doesn't require keeping track of indices (which are required to use `Array.splice`).

Example code:

```
var keptPlatforms = [];
// do stuff
if (mcContent.mcPlayer.y + mcContent.mcPlayer.height > platformCloud.y) 
{
    mcContent.mcPlayer.y = platformCloud.y - mcContent.mcPlayer.height - 1;
    jump();
    mcContent.removeChild(platformCloud);
} else {
    keptPlatforms.push(platformCloud);
}
// later, after this cycle, use the new Array
platformClouds = keptPlatforms;
```

Now, the reason `platformsCloud.splice(platformCloud)` removes *all* items is because the first argument is coerced to an integer so it is equivalent to `platformsCloud.splice(0)` which says "remove the 0th-indexed item to the end of the array". And, this does indeed clear the array.

To use [`Array.splice`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000752.html), you'd have to do something like:

```
// inside a loop this approach may lead to O(n^2) performance
var i = platformClouds.indexOf(platformCloud);
if (i >= 0) {
    platformClouds.splice(i, 1); // remove 1 item at the i'th index
}
```

Comment: but then i'd have to make it check keptPlatforms instead of platformClouds right ?

Comment: @BrunoCharters Fixed a typo in the use of Array.splice - using Array.splice to *remove* items and creating a new array with only the elements to *keep* are two different approaches. I recommend not using Array.splice here. But yes, if you need to re-check the same platform multiple times a cycle (which should be looked at as it sounds inefficient), then you'll need to only look into the current items.

Comment: You could also use the filter functionality of the Array Class to filter the list down to objects with a valid reference to the stage and/or parent.