# Splicing a Javascript array from within the callback passed to forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have this code which is supposed to iterate over each item in an array, removing items based on some condition:

```js
//iterate over all items in an array
//if the item is "b", remove it.

var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

array.forEach(function(item) {
  if(item === "b") {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);
  }

  console.log(item);
});
```

Desired output:

```
a
b
c
```

Actual output:

```
a
b
```

Obviously the native forEach method doesn't check after each iteration whether the item has been deleted, so if it is then the next item is skipped.  Is there a better way of doing this, aside from overriding the forEach method or implementing my own class to use instead of an array?

Edit - further to my comment, I suppose the solution is to just use a standard for loop.  Feel free to answer if you have a better way.

Comment: Actually I can see why they wouldn't try to support this functionality - you would need to check whether the deleted item was the current item, otherwise you might skip backwards unnecessarily (e.g. if the check was just based on whether the length had reduced by one or something).  seems too complicated to implement.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Lets see why JavaScript behaves like this. According to the [ECMAScript standard specification for `Array.prototype.forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18),

when you delete an element at index 1, the element at index 2 becomes the element at index 1 and index 2 doesn't exist for that object.

Now, JavaScript looks for element 2 in the object, which is not found, so it skips the function call.

That is why you see only `a` and `b`.

---

The actual way to do this, is to use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

array = array.filter(function(currentChar) {
    console.log(currentChar);   // a, b, c on separate lines
    return currentChar !== "b";
});
console.log(array);             // [ 'a', 'c' ]
```

Comment: +1 but, if you need to make any change to the array item (as I did in my circumstance - array of objects), as well as filter out items, best to use `reduce`.

Comment: ? you cannot log anything to the console after a `return` statement

Comment: @Blauhirn No, you can't.

Comment: @JuanBiscaia that is my point. In the above example, there is a logging statement *after* the return.

Comment: @Blauhirn oh, ok, sorry, I was in a hurry and didn't notice you aren't asking a question, my bad.

Answer (score 26):

One possibility would be to use the `array.slice(0)` function, which creates a copy ([clone](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array)) of the array and thus the iteration is separated from the deletion.

Then the only change to the original approach using `array.forEach` would be to change it to `array.slice(0).forEach` and it will work:

```
array.slice(0).forEach(function(item) {
    if(item === "b") {
        array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
    alert(item)
});
```

After the forEach, the array will contain only `a` and `c`.

A [jsFiddle demo can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/zSvTk/).

Comment: Also if you use lodash/underscore, you could do `_.clone(array).forEach(function (item) { ... })`

Comment: This is interesting, but it involves a lookup on each iteration, though the searched array diminishes in size. It would be faster to write a for loop and mind your index.

Comment: `forEach` has an index already. no need for `indexOf`

Comment: @Curcuma_ at this case using the `forEach` index will not work try it for yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Array.prototype.filter` as in thefourtheye's answer is a good way to go, but this could also be done with a `while` loop. E.g.:

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c"];
let i = 0;

while (i < array.length) {
    const item = array[i];

    if (item === "b") {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }

    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: end block of while have only closing curly brace" } "
its should not " }); " 
by applying this minor changes, code will compile successfully

Comment: Very true @AvnishPatel, good catch! Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to use the `array.reduceRight` function to avoid the skip:

```
//iterate over all items in an array from right to left
//if the item is "b", remove it.

const array = ["a", "b", "c"];

array.reduceRight((_, item, i) => {
    if(item === "b") {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}, null);

console.log(array);
```

After the `reduceRight`, the array will contain only `a` and `c`.

Comment: If used like this, it ignores the item at the last position. The accumulator (defined as `_` ) contains the first object from the array if no initialValue is passed. **You need to pass a 2nd argument (initialValue)** to `array.reduceRight(callback, initialValue)`.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks! If no initial value is supplied, the last element in the array will be used and skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = ["a", "b", "c"];
let i = array.length;
while (i--) {
    if (array[i] === "b") {
       array.splice(i, 1);
       break;
    }
}
console.log(item);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.