# Could not delete row from array using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need one help. I need to delete row from an array as per some condition using JavaScript. I am explaining my code below:

```
var arr = [{
        'value': '',
        'name': 'Rajeev'
      }, {
        'value': '1',
        'name': 'Raj'
      }, {
        'value': '',
        'name': 'Ram'
      }];


for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]['value']==''){
       arr.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Here after any value is deleting the array index is changing so it can not be deleted properly at every condition. I need to delete the row whose `value ==''`. Please help me.

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end, because [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) reduces the length of the array.

In your code, and if you splice, you have to keep the index at the same index, without incrementing.

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (arr[i]['value'] == '') {
       arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = arr.filter(element => element.value != '')
```

Comment: It'll be best if you set it to `arr` like `arr = arr.filter(element => element.value != '')`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Doruk  array.filter creates a new array object filled with elements that satisfies given predicate. I've edited my answer accordingly since the poster wants to get rid of these elements permanently.

Answer (score 0):

It will skip elements since removing element will change the index, but you are not updating the value of `i`. Do it in reverse order to avoid such problems, i.e, end to start.

```
var i = arr.length;

while(i--){
    if(arr[i]['value']==''){
       arr.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new array, adding the items that are not '' and replacing the old with new ? Replace your loop with code below and see if it works.

```
var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]['value'] !== '') {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
arr = newArr;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sno3pphs/

Answer (score 0):

Wont work because the lenth of your array is dynamically changing when you remove an element. You have to decrease the i variable. Try:

```
var arr = [{
        'value': '',
        'name': 'Rajeev'
      }, {
        'value': '1',
        'name': 'Raj'
      }, {
        'value': '',
        'name': 'Ram'
      }];


for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]['value']==''){
       arr.splice(i,1);
       i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the size of the array but keep increasing the index, if you want to change array size while running a loop a suggest you use

```
for each (var item in arr) { 
 if(item.val==''){
       arr.splice(item ,1);
       i--;
    }
```

of you can do it in a more efficient way like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811630/splicing-a-javascript-array-from-within-the-callback-passed-to-foreach)

```
array = arr.filter(function(currentChar) {
    return currentChar !== " ";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using lodash you can filter it out easily

the first parameter will be your array and the function returns value without ''

```
var fArray = _.remove(arr, function(obj) {
return ( obj.value  != '' );  });
```

fArray will be your desired array with value not ''