# decrease count value for array inside objects and count once reach zero automatically remove that object using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i have one object and its having service array i checked if any service id and offer id match with object its decrease count value and once count reach zero need to remove that object.[please check my try in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5j61zff/1/). i can able to reduce but while reaching zero not able to remove

```
const obj = {
name:'saloon',
services:[
   {
     sid:1,
     offid:20,
     count:2
   },
   {
     sid:2,
     offid:18,
     count:1
   },
   {
     sid:3,
     offid:15,
     count:3
   }
]
}
```

given values : based on this service and offer id count should decrease once count reach zero need to remove that object

```
const servid = 2
const offid = 18
```

mycode

```
    obj.services = obj.services.map(data => {
      if(data.sid == servid && data.offid == offid ){
          return data.count > 1 && {
            sid:data.sid,
            offide:data.offid,
            count:data.count -1
          } 
        }else{
          return data
        }
    })
     console.log(obj);
```

expected result :

```
const result = {
            name:'saloon',
            services:[
                       {
                         sid:1,
                         offid:20,
                         count:2
                       },
                       {
                         sid:3,
                         offid:15,
                         count:3
                       }
                    ]
            }
```

Comment: Please include your code here, rather than linking to a fiddle. It means that people don't have to go to an external site to see the context.

Comment: @JustinBlank Hi okay now i included my code please check

Comment: @NarayananS Please consider using punctuation. The question is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array#forEach` to iterate through your array and check each `sid` and `offid` inside service, in case of match update the `count` value after that check if `count` value is less than or equal to zero, if it is, then using push its index into `indexes` array. After that, you can iterate through `indexes` array and delete those values in `services` array using `array#splice`.

```js
const obj = { name:'saloon', services:[ { sid:1, offid:20, count:2 }, { sid:2, offid:18, count:1 }, { sid:3, offid:15, count:3 } ] };

const servid = 2;
const offid = 18;
var indexes = [];
obj.services.forEach(function(service, index) {
  if(service.sid === servid && service.offid === offid){
    --service.count;
  }
  if(service.count <= 0)
      indexes.push(index);
});

indexes.reverse().forEach(function(index){
  obj.services.splice(index, 1);
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Slicing an array while going over it with forEach is a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811782/5734311

Comment: No problem, however your answer is now a duplicate of the answer I gave 5 hours earlier.

Comment: I have updated the solution using different approach.

Comment: This, again, will not work. Just like before, slicing `obj.services` will shift the indexes, and if there's more than one element in `indexes`, the second slice will target the wrong element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.forEach()` to decrease the count, then `.filter()` to remove elements with count == 0:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'saloon',
  services: [{
    sid: 1,
    offid: 20,
    count: 2
  }, {
    sid: 2,
    offid: 18,
    count: 1
  }, {
    sid: 3,
    offid: 15,
    count: 3
  }]
}

const servid = 2
const offid = 18

obj.services.forEach((data, i) => {
  if (data.sid == servid && data.offid == offid) {
    data.count--;
  }
})
obj.services = obj.services.filter(data => data.count > 0);

console.log(obj);
```