# splice is not deleting when using forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When the products Line.Id match against refunds Id, it should delete the object from the refund variable.

The refund variable should only have only 1 line remaining which would be:

```
refunds = {
  Lines: [
  {LineId: "444"}
  ]
}
```

What did I do wrong?

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/ua8f1a5x/8/

```js
 products = {
      Items: [{
          Name: "Item Name 1",
          LineId: "111",
          Status: [],
        },
        {
          Name: "Item Name 2",
          LineId: "222",
          Status: [],
        },
        {
          Name: "Item Name 3",
          LineId: "333",
          Status: [],
        }
      ]
    }
    
    refunds = {
      Lines: [
      {LineId: "222"},
      {LineId: "111"},
      {LineId: "444"}
      ]
    }
    
    
     refunds.Lines.forEach((refundItem, refundIndex) => {
        console.log("Checking Id " + refundItem.LineId);
         
         products.Items.forEach((Item) => {
             if (refundItem.LineId == Item.LineId) {
                 Item.Status.push({Name: "Refunded"});
                 
                 //Delete  object from refund
                 refunds.Lines.splice(refundIndex, 1);
             }
         });
     });
     
     
     console.log(refunds);
     console.log(products);
```

Comment: Please check this issue i think it is possible duplicate of [Splicing a Javascript array from within the callback passed to forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811630/splicing-a-javascript-array-from-within-the-callback-passed-to-foreach)

Comment: modifying/deleting items from the array when iterating over it is not a good idea

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Answer the solution.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` iterates over the *static* array as it was when `forEach` was called (and, as said, mutating an object while you're iterating over it will result in confusion). In this situation, you should use `filter` instead:

```js
const products = {
  Items: [{
      Name: "Item Name 1",
      LineId: "111",
      Status: [],
    },
    {
      Name: "Item Name 2",
      LineId: "222",
      Status: [],
    },
    {
      Name: "Item Name 3",
      LineId: "333",
      Status: [],
    }
  ]
}

const refunds = {
  Lines: [{
      LineId: "222"
    },
    {
      LineId: "111"
    },
    {
      LineId: "444"
    }
  ]
}

refunds.Lines = refunds.Lines.filter(refundItem => {
  console.log("Checking Id " + refundItem.LineId);
  const foundProduct = products.Items.find(({
    LineId
  }) => LineId === refundItem.LineId);
  if (foundProduct) {
    foundProduct.Status.push({
      Name: "Refunded"
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});


console.log(refunds);
console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically just use filter()

```js
products = {
  Items: [{
      Name: "Item Name 1",
      LineId: "111",
      Status: [],
    },
    {
      Name: "Item Name 2",
      LineId: "222",
      Status: [],
    },
    {
      Name: "Item Name 3",
      LineId: "333",
      Status: [],
    }
  ]
}

refunds = {
  Lines: [{
      LineId: "222"
    },
    {
      LineId: "111"
    },
    {
      LineId: "444"
    }
  ]
}

refunds.Lines = refunds.Lines.filter(e => ! products.Items.some(x => x.LineId === e.LineId));
console.log(refunds)
```

Comment: What about push status I had?

Answer (score 1):

> What did I do wrong?

`refundIndex` doesn't get appropriated when the array which is being iterated is also getting mutated.

Use `filter` instead.

```
refunds.Lines.filter( s => !products.Items.find( t => t.LineId == s.LineId ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var products = {
  Items: [{
      Name: "Item Name 1",
      LineId: "111",
      Status: [],
    },
    {
      Name: "Item Name 2",
      LineId: "222",
      Status: [],
    },
    {
      Name: "Item Name 3",
      LineId: "333",
      Status: [],
    }
  ]
};

var refunds = {
  Lines: [
  {LineId: "222"},
  {LineId: "111"},
  {LineId: "444"}
  ]
};

refunds.Lines = refunds.Lines 
                .filter( s => !products.Items.
                    find( t => t.LineId == s.LineId ) );

console.log( refunds );
```