# array splice not working as expected inside the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, splice

Expected output : `['jan']`
Actual output: `['jan', 'apple']`

`forEach` function gets stopped after the splice operation. 
the commented code is working as expected but when I try to use similar with foreach, the code is not working as expected.

```js
var mainArr = ['jan', 'feb', 'apple'];
var exArr = ['feb', 'apple'];
removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr);

function removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr) {
  mainArr.forEach((item, index) => {

    if (exArr.includes(item)) {
      console.log(item);
      mainArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(mainArr);

  });
}

// function removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr){

//     const output = [];
//     for(let element of mainArr){
//         if(!exArr.includes(element)){
//             output.push(element);
//         }

//     return output;
//     }   
// }
```

Comment: You're modifying the array while iterating over it.

Comment: You'd be better off using `.filter()` on `mainArr` to create a new array.

Comment: @Amy But the following code also does the same. Modifying while iterating the same array


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
   if ( arr[i] === 5) {
     arr.splice(i, 1); 
   }
}

//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

Comment: @Nash Because that is still changing the contents of the array... Maybe you should look at the documentation for `splice`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mainArr = ['jan', 'feb', 'apple'];
const exArr = ['feb', 'apple'];

const filterArr = (mainArr, exArr) => {
  return mainArr.filter((char) => {
    return exArr.indexOf(char) === -1;
  });
}
console.log(filterArr(mainArr, exArr))
```

You can simply use a filter and a indexOf to achive that.

Comment: This solution looks perfect ! But any way to do the same with forEach instead of Array.prototype.filter();

Answer (score 0):

For keeping the same object reference of `mainArr`, you could iterate from the end of the array and remove unwanted parts without violating the index.

```js
function removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr) {
    var i = mainArr.length;
    while (i--) if (exArr.includes(mainArr[i])) mainArr.splice(i, 1);
}

var mainArr = ['jan', 'feb', 'apple'],
    exArr = ['feb', 'apple'];

removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr);
console.log(mainArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read answer of [Splicing a Javascript array from within the callback passed to forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811630/splicing-a-javascript-array-from-within-the-callback-passed-to-foreach) for more info.

Use filter instead.

```js
var mainArr = ['jan', 'feb', 'apple'];
var exArr = ['feb', 'apple'];
mainArr = removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr);
console.log(mainArr)
function removeGivenArr(mainArr, exArr) {
  return mainArr.filter((item) => !exArr.includes(item)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The forEach stopped because splice does it’s work in place. The actual array gets mutated and brought down the last index to 1 Upto which the iteration has been done already.